# Allow table to scroll but keep textbox element visible at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table with a fixed header, a scrolling body and a text box underneath the table. I want the visible table area to automatically resize to fill the browser window with the textbox still visible at the bottom. It works how I'd like with the div height set to 200px, but if I set it to 100% to fill the page the entire page scrolls instead. How can I have the table stretch/shrink to fit the page and keep the textbox visible at the bottom? Thank you!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="tableFixHead">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th>Test4</th>
        <th>Test5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
      <td>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
      <td>data5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
</div>
<div class="mainScreen">
<form method="POST">
    <input name="text" id ="input">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
      .mainScreen {
          height: 30px;
          bottom: 0;
      }
      .tableFixHead {
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 200px;
      }
      .tableFixHead table{
        height: 100%;
      }
      .tableFixHead thead th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      th, td {
        padding: 4px 16px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }
      th {
        background: #eee;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `overflow-y: auto;` from `.tableFixHead` and add `position: sticky;` to `.mainScreen`:

```css
.mainScreen {
  height: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
}

.tableFixHead {
  height: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead table {
  height: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 4px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
        <th>Test4</th>
        <th>Test5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
        <td>data2</td>
        <td>data3</td>
        <td>data4</td>
        <td>data5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="mainScreen">
  <form method="POST">
    <input name="text" id="input">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the text box is at the bottom out of sight, I'd like the table to scroll but the text box to always be visible at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` in the parent div (`.tableFixHead`) and then, add `flex-grow: 1` to the `table`.